# Python Library for question answering based on document

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

I am looking for a library that does question-answering on a document. To be more specific, I want to give it a document, a query, and I want an answer for that query based on the document. I know pre-trained models are available for this, but most of them are large (over 10 GB) and need a lot of computational power. I need this for a school project, so I want something smaller and simpler that I can run on my laptop. An API based service will also do.
Also, I have made the rest of my project in python, so it will be good if the library is in python too.